# How to display delete message in correct row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Below is a function where it controls whatever happens after a file has finished uploading in its own table row. Each table row consists of a file input where the user can upload a file and then the name of the file is appended within it's own table row.

If the file was successful then it displays a successful message, if upload was not successful then it displays a message stating there is an error. But I also have another function within the function where the user can delete a file by clicking on the "Delete" button. The only problem I have is with this line of code:

```
$(".imagemsg").html(data);
```

Let's say that I have 2 table rows, and I delete a file in the first row, the message within .imagemsg should only be displayed in the first row as that was the row the deletion occured, it shouldn't display the message in the first and second row.

So my question is what do I need to add to `$(".imagemsg").html(data);` so that the message is only displayed within the row the deletion of the file occured and not in all `.imagemsg` which is in every row?

Below is full code:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

         var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

        $(this).parent().remove();

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
      .done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg").html(data);
       });


    });

      return true;   
}
```

CALL BACK FUNCTION:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```

I heard that it is best if this will be done but I don't know how to code this:

Pass the relevant element to the callback function. You already have $(this), so you can probably get the right row from that and put it in a variable, then access it in the callback to put the result in the right place.

UPDATE:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      var counter = 0;
      counter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+counter+'">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

         var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
      .done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg" + counter).html(data);
       });

       $(this).parent().remove();

    });

      return true;   
}
```

Comment: put $(this).parent().remove();  after outputting message. You trying to add message to deleted element.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one row with class *imagemsg*, your code

```
$(".imagemsg").html(data);
```

will load it in all of them

To index your way in, you can try

```
$(".imagemsg").eq(0).html(data);
```

for the first one

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/peCze/)

Alternatively change `class="imagemsg"` to `id="imagemsgN"` where *N* is incremented and unique for each row. Then you change to `$("#imagemsg"+counter)` to get to it

Comment: But if .eq(0) does it for first one, then for each row do I need to create a variable such as $counter++ and do eq($counter++)?

Comment: Can't I keep it as a class rather than change it to id? I have updated my code to show you the solution I am trying but it is still not doing it. Update is at bottom of question

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.net to show your issue including the relevant html

Comment: Go on this link [here](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php). Click on the Add button a couple of times to display a couple of rows and then upload files in each row. After upload delete a file, you will find out there is a delete message which appears but it appears in all rows, it should just appear in the row you have deleted the file from

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".msg").html(...)

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to add a counter, and then .imagemsg is becomes ".imagemsg".$counter, then a msg returned actually only goes to relevant line - untested code but you get the idea.

eg

```
$counter++;
if (success == 1){ 
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'.$counter.'">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';       
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');  
      } 
      else { 
         result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>'; 
      } 


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) { 

         var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name'); 

        $(this).parent().remove(); 

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name) 
      .done(function(data) { 
        $(".imagemsg".$counter).html(data); 
       });
```

Comment: Is this PHP syntax or does jQuery allow the dot as concatenation symbol?? `$(".imagemsg".$counter)`

Comment: I have updated code at bottom of question but still can't get it to work

Comment: It may need a + to add the counter number to the name - if its not working what out put of html source do you have behind it now? in case thats not right?